# 100% width background only filling to the right

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

UPDATE: The reason it wasn't working is because the element with width: 100% was inside a div class="container" element. Removing that fixed the problem! (don't have enough rep to answer the question myself yet, just wanted to let viewers know it's been solved though.)

I am teaching myself the blueprint css framework, and I'm having trouble with the following html/css. I can't seem to the class `bigBox` to fill 100% of the page's width (it fills up 100% to the right, but it's aligned with the other content on the left.)

How can I get this to work the way it was intended? Thanks!

```
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <!-- screen is default blueprint framework file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />  
    <!-- import custom styles -->
    <style>
        #topmenu {float:right; margin-top: 50px; /*margin-right: -30px;*/}
        #topmenu ul {list-style: none outside none; }
        #topmenu ul li { display: inline;  }
        #topmenu ul li a { text-decoration: none;  
                           padding: 5px;}
        #topmenu .last { padding-right: 0px; }
        #topmenu .current { font-weight: bold; }

        .bigBox { width: 100%; position: absolute;
                 background-color: blue; height: 430px;
                }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- logo -->
        <div class="span-12">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- top menu -->
        <div class="span-12 last">
            <nav id="topmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="">Option 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>      

        <br class="clear"/>
        <div class="bigBox">
            <div class="span-14">
                <h2>Content Left</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="span-10 last">
                <h2>Content Right</h2>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should have enough rep to answer and accept this now, yes? :)

Answer (score 0):

"The reason it wasn't working is because the element with width: 100% was inside a div class="container" element. Removing that fixed the problem!"

answered and made CW for you.